# Add N numbers without using + or -

Tags: code-golf, restricted-source

Given N integers, output the sum of those integers.

### Input

You may take the integers in any reasonable format, including:

- `stdin`
- arguments
- an array or list

### Rules

- Your code must not include the characters `+` or `-`.
- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) apply. Take note of [Abusing native number types to trivialize a problem](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8245/89298).
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf). The shortest code in each language wins, which means that I will not be accepting an answer.

### Testcases

```
n=2, 1, 2 -> 3
n=2, 2, 2 -> 4
n=2, 9, 10 -> 19
n=2, 7, 7 -> 14
n=2, 8, 8 -> 16
n=2, -5, 3 -> -2
n=2, -64, -64 -> -128
n=2, -3, 0 -> -3
n=2, 0, 3 -> 3
n=2, 0, 0 -> 0
n=2, -1, -1 -> -2
n=2, -315, -83 -> -398
n=2, 439, 927 -> 1366
n=3, 1, 2, 3 -> 6
n=3, 2, 2, 5 -> 9
n=3, 0, 9, 10 -> 19
n=3, 7, 0, 7 -> 14
n=3, 8, 8, 0 -> 16
n=3, -5, 3, -2 -> -4
n=3, -64, -64, 16 -> -112
n=3, -3, 0, 0 -> -3
n=3, 0, 3, 0 -> 3
n=3, 0, 0, 0 -> 0
n=3, -1, -1, -1 -> -3
n=3, -315, -83, -34 -> -432
n=3, 439, 927, 143 -> 1509
n=17, -74, 78, 41, 43, -20, -72, 89, -78, -12, -5, 34, -41, 91, -43, -23, 7, -44 -> -29
```

Testcases with partial sums that exceed 8 bits are only required if your integer type supports each partial sum (if any) and the final result. As a special case, `n=2, -64, -64 -> -128` is only required if your integer type can represent `-128`.

Testcases involving negative integers are only required if your language natively supports negative integers.

Comment: I have one which I think is neat enough to be a notable mention though it doesn't strictly abide by the rules. Instead of summing a list, it only adds 2 numbers... Any chance I can still add it and let the votes decide?

Comment: @AviF.S., that would not be a valid solution to the challenge.

Comment: @Avi If you create another function that does the rest of the adding, then yes. Otherwise, no.

Comment: I see you've had mercy on languages that don't support numbers that require 8 bits, a generous allowance. Any chance it's also alright if our language doesn't support negative numbers? (I don't mean to keep poking at the question, but I'd really love to be able to submit answers in languages not meant for this sort of thing and still have them be reasonably elegant, even if not short!)

Comment: @AviF.S. That's acceptable. The other was not, as that would make the challenge extremely trivial.

Comment: Wonderful, and completely understood! Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 14):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 2 bytes

**Tr** *finds the trace of the matrix or tensor list*

```
Tr
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n277P6Tof0BRZl6JgkN6dLWuuYmOgrmFjoKJIRAb6yjoGhkACXMjHQULSxADKKVrCOTpmuooGAPV6oIUWhqCGGDVQMIcxDGpjf3/HwA)

Comment: @a'_' As far as I remember, it sums the elements on the diagonal of a matrix, or, if it's actually a vector, just sums everything.

Answer (score 10):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>97 95 93 88</s> 87 bytes

Solution that doesn't use the built-in `sum`, `eval` or `exec`:

*-2 bytes thanks to @JonathanAllan!*
*-1 byte thanks to @ovs!*

```python
x=y=1
for i in input():x<<=i*(i>0);y<<=abs(i)
y/=x
print" ~"[x<y],len(bin(x/y|y/x)[3:])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVDbbqMwEH33V4zoQ2BrN4AJhWzIj0R5cIK7tQQGgWlBWu2vZ8c2SdVKyDrHzJyL@8W8dzq9XbtaVpvN5jZXS5WQt24ABUrj108mjPbz4VCpX6E6xtHvBbG4jKGKyLKtZtIPSpsA/gWn@bCcaSN1eFE6nLfL32U7Rye@P0c31H4ZzaD6MCJEtX03GBiX0Tk1SktrhhxnaqX3BOAJBilqHwCErkHOvbwaWeP9ODUGR0Y6QAWt6ENU9urUar2MfaNMGLBjEEU459TarlZvy70QmA51zDRoMO9ydfmU8Cm0Vfa8gka0l1rs5YdowhGDA7iy6AxW/cGDU/A8PAfngBIfffK64mom0eBQ92cQLf6Ss7yG9rGjr93gllBIgR2Bk3RFGSkpJLGFSUleKbw6mJGCQuFgTtiOAreYpYTlGQU8HE3SgjBOwa0zTuJ1ziF3GROGniy5b/MEtVjh1XhZkIyjf5l6V57nxEZcZXKXksLOktJq/sgaf4@7et4To5GryLJHalzPffIk9cm/h1@Zz/@jwqMG/6qBB/dPkfH00QVdMlcg2cXlfw)

**Input**: a comma separated list of numbers, from stdin.
**Output**: the sum is printed to stdout. If the sum is negative, the `~` sign is used instead of `-` due to source code restriction.

**How**: Let \$p\$ be the sum of all positive numbers in the list, and \$n\$ be the magnitude of the sum of all negative numbers. Then the sum of the list is \$p-n\$.

Let \$x=2^p\$ and \$y=2^n\$, then \$\frac xy=2^{p-n}\$.

Thus if the sum is positive (aka \$x>y\$), we can calculate the sum by counting the number of zeros in the binary representation of \$\frac xy\$. Otherwise, we can calculate the magnitude of the sum as the number of zeros in the binary representation of \$\frac yx\$.

Comment: `x<<=i*(i>0);y<<=abs(i*(i<0))` saves two over using `max` and `min`.

Comment: [85 bytes](https://tio.run/##XVDbbqMwEH33V4zoQ8zWbgATCtmQH6n64AR3awkMAqcFabW/nh3bJFUrIescM3MuHhb73pvseu4bVW82m@tcL3VK3voRNGiD33CxNN7Ph0Otf1F9TOLfC2J5mqiOybKtZzKM2tgI/kUv82F5Za0y9KQNnbfL32U7xzEXV1R@muyoBxoToruhHy1My@R9Wm2Us0KOM402ewLwAKOSTbAHaRpQ86DOVjV4P11aiyMTG6GGTg4UlYM6c1pP09BqSyN@jOIY57xa1zf6bbnVAdujjr2MBuy7Wl0@FXxK45QDr6GV3amRe/UhWzphcABfFZ3Bqd959BI9jo/Ra8RIiH4JuvJsL7LFof7PKDv8pWZ1pu6p46/d6JoyyIAfQZBsRTmpGKSJg2lFnhk8e5iTkkHpYUH4joFwmGeEFzkDPDxNs5JwwcCvc0GSdc4jf5kQjp48vW2LFLV4GdREVZJcoH@VBVdRFMRFXGUKn5LBzpHKaf7ImnyPu3reEqORr8jze2pcL0LyNAvJv4dfWcj/o8K9hviqgYcIT5GL7N4FXXJfIN0l1X8)

Comment: @ovs Thanks! I cannot use `-3` since it contains `-`, but can still save 1 byte with `y/=x`.

Answer (score 9):

## JavaScript (ES6), 21 bytes

Takes input as an array of integers.

```javascript
a=>eval(a.join`\x2B`)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rZVNasMwFIT3PYWWMUiJ/mxJi3TRa7SFmNQpCcYOTQm9vfukQBeWtOp4ISwQfGjezOjS3/vb8et8/RbT/DEsp/3S75@Hez9u@u1lPk@Htx/9cmiW4zzd5nHYjvPn5rR5VZzp96ZhoG@3Y@ZphdBwhF0jAmdK4hiEUGHNcJw57DVUdg/PmQczujVDtJwZqFZCZ4zOckYLCBMZSvuMYjjDTl1k5pVQsYr5kNBbRITMlKKYCwWDlGduFDlLeJBcaRohm7k1lPWgHc5ZynRZRmIrAgdPlK7Uipy1QEQoGAtZjLVWlMBirLYiMCP1ViT7apx7ba0VaSYdAJNaUeliK@LkqrYidiLFVsQiKq0Ia8aiUn@tSIv5/3uYfGV0rRXJWRbQWjEhrcyyLhxZ11EULYlmU1poRMJRj/kQf3zUknYpTNHr8WCICj9O0@Li5qFDekXC8gs)

---

## JavaScript (ES6), 40 bytes

Takes input as an array of integers.

```javascript
a=>a.reduce(g=(x,y)=>y?g(x^y,(x&y)*2):x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rZXfaoMwGMXv9xS5GjqS1vzRmIHdg4wNpLXSUepot6FP775Y2IVJrna8CAYCP3K@c04@2p/2tr@ePr/EZTh087GZ22bXbq7d4XvfZX2TjXzKm9300mfj@8Sz8XHKn1T@PObzfrjchnO3OQ99dsxeJWfqLc8Z6NtumX5YIRQcYdYIx5kscAxCSLdmWM4s9hoyuEfNWQ1mVGuGKDnTUK2EChiV4YwWEMYzpKoDiuYMO3URmLeAihXNRwG9hUcUgVIUcyFhkPjMtSRniRok1zINF8zcaMq6UxbnLKmrICO@FYGDJ0oVa0XOSiDCRYyFLMZUKxbAYky2IjAj6VYk@yqce02qFWkmFQCztKJU0VbEyZVsRexEoq2IRSRaEdaMUaX@WpEW/f/3cPGVVqlWJGcZQGv5hJRFkHVhybqWomhINLOkhUYkLPVY7fxP7bWk3RIm73V/0HmF76dpsX5z12F5Rdz8Cw)

Comment: Amazing formula! Waiting for an explanation on why this will eventually terminate.

Comment: @SurculoseSputum It is quite similar to a binary addition by hand: the `XOR` does the addition without the carries which are processed separately by the doubled `AND`. The recursion stop when there's no more carry. It is described [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/add-two-numbers-without-using-arithmetic-operators/) for instance, and some other variants can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068033/add-two-integers-using-only-bitwise-operators).

Answer (score 6):

## [APL (dzaima/APL)](https://github.com/dzaima/APL), 2 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

Anonymous tacit prefix function

```apl
1⊥
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVCxDcIwEOyZ4kookPy2E9vjREKRkECiZgAKCkTDCNTZgVGyiPknkvMOUPh99z6/79ydDtvdudsfu9yPl/s603h95s1qvD2Y9iDYgq3CCWQKCQgFR8SCX0MDp1jrP0V1HOYpRmmN6r8GkqVvUcM1znLvEpIN2rUaxr7RqNEL76Z2X73M/rna7wygto5RB6nYjzB/Agn0y1Qgrz8xeIQIT3ws1oy0LGKSPcpcO/kWn6xK8tYkdRyWsc9v)

Simply evaluates a "digit" list in base 1.

Comment: Absolutely brilliant! How ever did it occur to you? The best part is it's no longer than the normal way. Replacing `+/` with `1⊥` in all golfed APL has to be the best way of obfuscating and impressing people ever...

Comment: @AviF.S. It is [a common trick in tacit APL](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/153435/43319) due to it being a dyadic function application rather than a monadic one which cannot be composed with a function on its left.

Comment: Whoops. Now that it's documented, I feel silly acting like it was so novel... But I do still think it's a brilliant trick!

Answer (score 6):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>50</s> <s>45</s> <s>43</s> 38 bytes

```c
f(s,e)char**s;{s=s<e?&f(&s[1])[*s]:0;}
```

*-7 bytes thanks to @S.S. Anne*
*-5 bytes thanks to @Bubbler*

Takes for input start and end pointers. It uses the fact that the address of `&a[b]` equals `a+b`. Other than that, even I am a bit confused as to how this works.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZcqxCsIwGATg3ac4Cpak/oGWUlBj8UFqhzQ2taBRGreQZ49RBweHOzi@02LSOkbDHI1cX9RSFE5617rDeMwNy11X9bwrXL8vZYjXu53wKdX1aOFFRRANYUeoypRtkPidhu8pQU0og1zN9ombmi3j8HgsaRqWrc8nmxEMUwSFDRrO5T8OhCFh/cYQXw)

Comment: Nicely done, but fails on multiple test cases, like `0, 3, 0` and `7, 0, 7` and `0, 9, 10`.

Comment: You're right, let me see if I can fix that...

Comment: It also requires a terminating `0` element.

Comment: I think I've fixed it, but if not, please tell me.

Comment: Nice. [45 bytes](https://tio.run/##ZcpBDoIwFATQvaeYkEj@x08CISRqJR4EWZRKlYXEUHdNz15LXLqYxcwbUz6MidGSk4nn5VM45V3nLtM1JzJPvRZcOO4t5a6vBx7OlQox/aD7AR18WQvKVnAS1FXKMShsPP44TY2gCmq3jS89L8TweK@pWsr299uSCSxpgcYBLbP6x1EwJmw2DPEL) using return hack.

Comment: Cool trick, thanks.

Comment: [43 bytes](https://tio.run/##ZcqxCsIwGATg3ac4Cpak/oWGUlBj8UFihiQ22sEijVvIs8cUR4cb7r5z7cO5nD0LNPF5@TRBxjCGy3StPauDEpor5p5mbXgT9LmTKZcXjNIYEVtBaAfCiSC6kmOS2Nj@uEw9oUtyt40vMy@MI@K9lupZtb/florgmSEYHDBwLv/REmzBfsOUvw) using the brackets to avoid parentheses.

Comment: [38 bytes](https://tio.run/##ZcqxCsIwGATg3ac4Cpak/oGWUlBj8UFqhzQ2taBRGreQZ49RBweHOzi@02LSOkbDHI1cX9RSFE5617rDeMwNy11X9bwrXL8vZYjXu53wKdX1aOFFRRANYUeoypRtkPidhu8pQU0og1zN9ombmi3j8HgsaRqWrc8nmxEMUwSFDRrO5T8OhCFh/cYQXw) with even more pointer abuse (and 64-bit ints, because TIO runs on a 64-bit machine.)

Comment: @Bubbler TIO doesn't have 64-bit `int`. No operating system that I know of uses that ABI (including but not limited to BSD, Linux, Windows, and Mac). `long` is 64-bit on Linux and Mac, though, and TIO runs on Mac.

Comment: @S.S.Anne I meant 64-bit integer type (the input arrays are in `long long[]` type). Also, I believe TIO runs on a Linux, not Mac, because [the syscall numbers for Linux x86-64 work well on TIO](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/201711/78410) (at least `write=1` and `exit=60`).

Comment: @Bubbler Sorry, I know it runs on Linux. I had just written "Linux and Mac" and then wrote "Mac" instead of "Linux". Anyway, on x86-64 Linux, `long` is always 64-bit.

Answer (score 6):

## [W](https://github.com/A-ee/w), 1 [bytes](https://github.com/A-ee/w/wiki/Code-Page)

Takes input as a list and... just a summation function... :-)

```
J
```

## [W](https://github.com/A-ee/w) [`j`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14337/command-line-flags-on-front-ends/14339#14339), 0 [bytes](https://github.com/A-ee/w/wiki/Code-Page)

Haha, even more cheaty! The `j` flag automatically evaluates the `J` command at the end of the source code.

Answer (score 5):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 1 [byte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Trivial challenges get trivial solutions!

```
x
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=eA&input=WzEsMl0)

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/)/[Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 3 bytes

```python
sum
```

[Try it online (Py 3)!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzv7g0939BUWZeiUaaRrSJsaWOgqWReaym5n8A) or [Try it online (Py 2)!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzv7g0939BUWZeiUaaRrSJsaWOgqWReaym5n8A)

Comment: Also works in Haskell, and many other languages I'm sure.

Answer (score 4):

## [GERMAN](https://esolangs.org/wiki/GERMAN), 141 bytes

```
EINGABESCHLEIFENANFANGSUBTRAKTIONRECHTSEINGABESCHLEIFENANFANGSUBTRAKTIONRECHTSADDITIONLINKSSCHLEIFENENDELINKSSCHLEIFENENDERECHTSRECHTSAUSGABE
```

Comment: i'm disappointed this is just another brainfuck derivative rather than some complex combination of  german words

Comment: @JoKing I am sorry to disappoint you. Unfortunately, programming languages not based on English are quite rare ...

Answer (score 4):

## [Mornington Crescent](https://github.com/padarom/esoterpret), <s>634</s> 537 bytes

```
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Parsons Green
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Temple
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Parsons Green
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Parsons Green
Take District Line to Bank
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Angel
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Bank
Take Circle Line to Bank
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tZJBCsIwEEX3nmIOkIDVSnWpFXSh4qIeIITBBptJmeT@NSnYLqSoCxcZZng/5PMz1jEZugdHUjN6jRS6rlIPhIvjUCMTnAwhBAc7RY9Zj/bGBzY6DOiq2DvycGBEmtDcWmvIB@QJXqFtG5yAR2Utsrcm1H@08Il/88aY0luAZa04Zg0lO@8nNFu6YzP7@QM@OR@vloZ1g9/YPQ@rER2/VkMWuYBiLSDP4lkKkIt5LMVCwHqTmohkFie5ErCMWpmEmyw1vTqWIg35Ew)

```
// initialize adder
Take Northern Line to Bank          // save input to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Parsons Green // get 0
Take District Line to Upminster     // set Upminster = 0

// set start of loop
Take District Line to Temple

// extract leading number
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Parsons Green

// add it to previous sum
Take District Line to Upminster     // accumulator = sum
                                    // Upminster = previous accumulator

// save sum in Upminster
Take District Line to Upminster

// get remaining string
Take District Line to Parsons Green

// check if it is equal to "" by translating the first char to its codepoint (0 if empty)
// we ride a few extra rounds here, adding 0s to the sum
Take District Line to Bank          // save string and 
                                    // get string of previous round
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross // swap accumulator with Charing Cross
                                    // and get codepoint of previous values' 
                                    // first char (that's from two rounds ago)
                                    // or 0 if empty

// if string is not empty (meaning, accumulator is non-zero), repeat
Take Northern Line to Angel

// else read sum
Take Northern Line to Bank          // get empty string
Take District Line to Upminster     // swap with Upminster

// and go home, outputting the number
Take District Line to Bank          // change lines, swapping data with Bank
Take Circle Line to Bank            // swap back
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent // go home
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/), 3 bytes

```python
sum
```

Built in function which does the job

**[Try it online](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPqfZhvzv7g0939BUWZeiUaaRrSxjqGRjmmspuZ/Q2MA)**

---

With no built-in, **36 bytes** in [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/):

-3 thanks to ovs!

```python
lambda a:eval(`a`.replace(*',\x2b'))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSHRKrUsMUcjITFBryi1ICcxOVVDS10npsIoSV1T839BUWZeiUaaRrSRjqmOrqGRjrGOrkUsUAIA)

Note: a single value may be represented as a singleton list ([meta](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11884/53748))

Comment: `'\x2b'` is one bytes shorter than `chr(43)`. Then `replace(*',\x2b')` is another two bytes shorter.

Comment: @ovs - very nice, thank you!

Comment: The built-in function also works in other versions.

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 94 bytes

```c
x,c;n(a,b){for(;b;b=x*2)x=a&b,a^=b;x=a;}f(a,t)int*a;{for(c=1;c<t;c=n(c,1))*a=n(*a,a[c]);c=*a;}
```

A non-trivial golfed reference implementation.

I realized I had worded myself out of an answer when I couldn't even use `+` or `-` for a counter variable.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVLRauMwEHz3VywNPax0RSzJqW1Uf4mbFlmxD8NVKUkoocbfnltJTeMLB8cJpJ3VjnZGQpb/tPZ8PqHVLjXYsrHf7VPd6rY@LSU71eZHi@albjVBPfXEObLBHZdGB6athbZPR21rl1oUjC0NoaVB09gNo20iTufFtusH14Ez@33qGFADcK@LhWs2jdtAnSR@580MLv3YDVuWjAnQCHTJAh6TUaCcMBllDBWKzMcCCx9KLH3ga1QhPuZIM0CFgZjFShYzLpCLWBZr5GWo5arCSvp@XnLSydWGmtuIncgIrmPLq5ns286XDhlCLmeeUDxebH0bu4C5uRt/yFU@84giVzc@Vys4vHd2ML/AmkMX9uJLi6IRhX/neAVe5AhFiZALmgqBy4yWQiKUlQdU4oIyMg@KuNwTK@FBYNNS@CT/Q9//B683QA2ZpvAEh@Gz2/Wpe5VsdcVNRl8DhoeHy5vC13jf0/k@vbvfPrs7hEgeNgiSMR21/i2lZlLqf6RUkFI3Un8hCrq8KDxvOv8G)

Answer (score 3):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + GNU utilities, 57 bytes

```bash
printf %.f $(bc -l<<<"99*l(e(`sed 's@ @/99)*e(@g'`/99))")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY7LasMwEEX38xUXkxI7MK1ejiTwwh/SRR5WaoOJS1zopv/ujuoYutDVMJo5R5fz3C/f/TAmPNK5wzjcEwHdJAGkaz@h2OVmgR@8L5@P4f51w8vrDbvycgWPTdMUMR7GMpWnOXXYzy3atxirQyrbj/0pl1VRLSuMukn4i4YBmRwRWpGHBwUEENewkkcHOcQWCqRyS@WKNVhLV9fgYMnZiGg8ZZpdeXWefDLVRlVPLpuNDH1c4U@8WgWb4r8FbN1mgnaW2Dv4AKfhMlKBvUGIcgXZM8gqkch7FNDfjJWfsHP0Cw)

Reads space-separated integers from stdin, and writes the output to stdout.

This applies the exponential function to each integer, multiplies the results, and then takes the natural logarithm of the product.  I need to scale the input numbers (and then "unscale" the result) so as not to overflow the exponentials on some of the starred test examples (that's what the `99*` and `/99` are doing there).

Answer (score 3):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 1 byte

```
s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/v/j//2hDHQUjHQXjWAA)

#### Explanation

```
s(Q)
 (Q) : Implicit evaluated input
s    : Sum the input
```

Answer (score 3):

## Mornington Crescent, 1267 bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##xZTPCsIwDMbvPkVewIMieNYpenAi6LzXEbbimoy0Cj79rIgT1Pofdu3vS/Mlgc@wkKbMMbVTQZsiuapaqS3CnMXlKAQzTQiOYaho23qMxjvrfzjDtU4di1Y1XOIeCZbaOhQb0FwezjjSkhb4Hry6GvkO4qU1WiixTBYmgkgBTVIaTSdnAT5VxnjbRrv8hy7/cJKUhIdGp7iu@uYGMbNkyuFDuEJTFvh53c@H/X5dTdU2eaa73jd8bDb@X@PzIZABUa7EJwlEwtYGNAPKsGi9ipePdhqc9klcxXXoebeX0OtAD/rQ7R0B)

Poorly golfed, may have to have another attempt tomorrow.

```
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take Northern Line to Euston
Take Victoria Line to Seven Sisters
Take Victoria Line to Victoria
Take Circle Line to Victoria
Take Circle Line to Bank
Take District Line to Parsons Green
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Parsons Green
Take District Line to Parsons Green
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Upney
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Parsons Green
Take District Line to Bank
Take Circle Line to Moorgate
Take Circle Line to Temple
Take Circle Line to Moorgate
Take Circle Line to Bank
Take District Line to Parsons Green
Take District Line to Upney
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Upney
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Upney
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Parsons Green
Take District Line to Bank
Take Circle Line to Moorgate
Take Circle Line to Hammersmith
Take Circle Line to Embankment
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Angel
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Upney
Take District Line to Bank
Take Circle Line to Bank
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
```

Comment: I realized today that my past self was smarter and that my "better" solution is wrong -- it misses the edge case 0, which causes the program to terminate prematurely in the case of an input such as `3 0 4 1`. Reverted, and see Dorian's Mornington Crescent answer as well for an improvement on how I handled this originally.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 1 [byte](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
S
```

A built-in monadic atom which given a list yields the sum.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/4////0aY6hkY6hrEA)**

---

No built-in, **2 bytes**:

```
ḅ1
```

Converts from base one to an integer.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjlbD////R5vqGBrpGMYCAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), `-hr`, 2 bytes

```
÷⅀
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N////8PZHrQ3//0ebWeoomBgZ6CgYmuoo6BrG/tfNKAIA)

The joys of not having implemented lists properly!  Simply item split and summate. Essentially uses a sum function, so no imaginary points for me.

Answer (score 2):

## Batch, 93 bytes

`43` is the ASCII code for `+`:

```
@!! 2>nul||cmd/q/v/c%0&&exit/b
set c=cmd/c
set/pn=
%c%exit 43
%c%set/a !n: =%=exitcodeascii%!
```

Takes input via `STDIN`, delimited by space.

Answer (score 2):

## [J](https://jsoftware.com), 4 bytes

```
1&#.
```

This was literally taken from [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/152191/91569).

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NydHNKE0v/v8/NzEzT8FWoaAoM69Eo7g0N9pQx0jHOFbz/38A), 3 bytes

```
sum
```

Function that takes an argument as a list e.g. `sum[1,2,3]` and returns the sum of the list.

Answer (score 2):

## [Brainetry](https://github.com/rojergs/brainetry), 143 bytes

```
a b c d e f
a b
a b c d e f
a b c d e f g h
a b c d e f g h
a b c d e

a b c d
a
a b c d e f g h i
a b c d e f
a b c d e f g h i

a b c d e f g
```

To try it online follow [this repl.it link](https://repl.it/github/rojergs/brainetry) and paste the code in the `btry/replit.btry` file, then press the green "Run" button. Does I/O as ASCII codepoints.

The program above is the golfed version of this program:

```
Let me sum some numbers carefully.
Carefully enough
so that I do not use
the plus or minus signs, that'd be awful.
After I do this, oh so very carefully,
I just have to ...
Move the pointer
left and right for
a while.
This is the main gist of the whole program.
Of course this sounds somewhat uninteresting.
That is because you, my dear reader, lack depth.
(Is it "depth"?
Maybe that's not the correct English word...)
```

Comment: These brainerty poems are always very interesting.

Comment: Do you need the blank lines in the golfed program?

Comment: @pppery not sure if you are just making fun or if you really think they are funny. Yes, the blank lines are needed. In Brainetry a blank line moves the pointer to the left edge of the tape, cf. [this quick reference table](https://github.com/rojergs/brainetry/wiki/quick%20reference)

Answer (score 2):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 4 bytes

```
_MSg
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P8/3jc4/f///4b/jQA)

`MS` maps a function to an iterable and sums its results.

`_` is the identity function.

`g` is the list of command line args.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 62/61 bytes

Without relying on sum in other functions.

```python
def f(i,x=0):
	for y in i:
		while y:x,y=x^y,(x&y)*2
	return x
```

Can be shortened to 61 by removing the function definition (-13), replacing `in i:` with `in eval(input()):` (+12) and print instead of return at the end (+0).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYrBCsMgEAXP8Sv2VLSsEF1Da8AvKe2pSoRigliqX28DgdLLwJs3WyvLmqj3pw8QeMTqRjGzIawZGsQEcR/DZ4kvD22u2Fx9NOT11MRZsyH78s4Jat9yTIUHflMI@i7AOSDBflaSmhDklXaQOX5pSP8lhiyC1RcEZego1DRa0b8)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 1 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
O
```

Input as a list.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##FYrLCcAwDMUWeg/iT7AzRQYIPbTQ/Udw3ZME0pj3I2/VrjoMRyRc4AbqAEORq5GgKDhhDnZf0vgfQ7T59QE) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##VY5LDsIwDESvUnU9keLEbZIVR@AAVRcgsWDFAgmpF@AAHJGLhIlp@SziseLxPF@uh@P5VG/Lru@e90fX75a6r6jTJAgzpmC1QDwlIbFmZFY3IDYZFXyti2geb9/eeidwYiMZ4HIbaCwoocUw36wkYLCVD8VvnHcKSXbFyoKMK24DrvoD/efCRf2yIWqXJ0XKUIHSEDxcCsiFkrkd0LDkcV4YZ56IxE7n@QU).

Slightly less boring:

```
1β
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##FYrLCcAwDMUWeg/iT7AzS@mhhSzYQbqS654kkMa8btlV8j5VB8MRCRe4gTrAUORqJCgKTpiD3Zc0/scQbX5@) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##VY7NDcIwDIVXqXp@keLEbZJTB6l6AIkDJw5ISF2AARiFQRiCRcqLafk5xM@Kn9/n03m3Px6Wyzy0zfN6a9phXuRxX7CMoyBMGIPVAvGUhMSakVldh1ilV/DVLqJ6vH17653AiY2kg8t1oLGghBrDfLOSgM5WPhS/cd4pJNkVKwvSr7gNuOoP9J8LF/XLhqhdnhQpQwVKQ/BwKSAXSuZ2QMWSx3lhnHkiEjudphc).

**Explanation:**

```python
O   # Sum the (implicit) input-list
    # (and output the result implicitly)

1β  # Convert the (implicit) input-list to base-1
    # (and output the result implicitly)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <del>60</del> 24 bytes

```powershell
$args-join[char]0x2b|iex
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/XyWxKL1YNys/My86OSOxKNagwiipJjO14v///7rG/3WN/uuaAgA)

-36 bytes thanks to @mazzy

Comment: you can to save some bytes [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/XyWxKL1YNys/My86OSOxKNagwiipJjO14v///7rG/3WN/uuaAgA "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Comment: @mazzy much thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## [Racket](https://racket-lang.org/), 133 bytes

```lisp
(define(f a[s 0])(if(null? a)s(let([c(car a)])(if(= 0 c)(f(cdr a)s)(f(cons((if(> 0 c)add1 sub1)c)(cdr a))((if(> 0 c)sub1 add1)s))))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY49DsIwDIV3TvEkBpwhUp0GWgbgIBVDSFtUEQXU0IHTg9MuCGHJ8s/3bL3R@Vv3fK@Di1eMy0Bt1w@xox6uSSjOioae4hTCCU4lCt2TGk/ejTIu8IACXlFPvs3LNLf3mCjD4wxd2zLSdGElwkWmvnAmyBo5nkNcDOkR3CtEiJMNMQxKAatfoFk@8F@ys8jJu7@0sqhqWIYtoU0BXRnUeyk1NBvoLUq5F75nKVlTopLOZnsf)

Well...

Answer (score 1):

## perl -ple, 18 bytes

```
s/ /\x2b/g;$_=eval
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYrBCsIwEAXv@Yp38Lqku9mQFPFPBFEoIoQ2tKX49a7b0wzM9Glt2WyLiPevvOL7enncpuPZzBgSiAeQDMEdCYocqChKhTI0nQlUBHV0VBALKCMpyPvIjvNJKG76W/r@WebNqLc/)

Reads a space separated list of numbers from `STDIN`, writes the sum to `STDOUT`.

## perl -MList::Util=sum -alpe, 8 bytes

```
$_=sum@F
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FY2xCgIxEAX7fMUrbBdukw3JHQhWVlpai4VFIHrBxN933VQzMA9ee35qVD3cj/37Op1VGd4RLyC/OHMECKKjJEgZwpAwEyh55NWQQexBEUFA1lc2zE1AMpPf3kbZ313peil9bNttlDrPlNqj/gE)

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), <s>20</s> 9 bytes

```php
array_sum
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRwMWlkmb7P7GoKLEyvrg09781F1dqcka@gkqahoJKYlF6mYKm9f//JsaW/y2NzAE)

still wondering if this is not too easy here..
EDIT: thanks to @640KB for saving 11 bytes!

Comment: Your answer could just be `array_sum` as an anonymous function for 9 bytes. https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRwMWlkmb7P7GoKLEyvrg09781F1dqcka@gkqahoJKYlF6mYKm9f//JsaW/y2NzAE

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know PHP would use the function properly when replacing what it seems to be an undefined constant. I also don't know yet all the rules of the site and would have left the semicolon inside the count too.

Comment: You are allowed to submit an anonymous "callable" function (example `function($x) { return $x+1; }`) which isn't really any different functionally than a pre-defined / built-in. While sometimes considered "not interesting", if there's a PHP function that answers the challenge then it's valid to submit just that. To note, there are other answers here doing the same (just with shorter built-in function names than PHP of course).

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, 3 Bytes

```
sum
```

calculates the sum of a list

Comment: This answer was already posted [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/203684/75323)

Comment: [Duplicate answers aren't invalid](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10812/76162), but users are encouraged to check for existing answers before posting

Answer (score 1):

## [C++ (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <sub><s>83</s></sub>, 110 bytes

```cpp
#include <iostream>
int n,x,c;int f(int i){while(i){c=n&i;n^=i;i=c<<1;}if(std::cin>>x)f(x);else std::cout<<n;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYzLCsIwFET3@YqAIAnUhYqb5vEpQrlN9EJ6W5oUAyXfHhudxXA4DAPLcnkB1HpCgrCNjmucY1rdMFmGlDh1uQPVyIvWKPfPG4MTB4ChMyp6GlRoQOurKuhFTGPfA5K1WXqRpXIhOv6385a0JlVqu5oGJCHZzviR35KVeuN3/vgC)

Explanation: Reads in integer inputs and preforms bit-wise addition.

I tried to simplify the carry step [like this](https://tio.run/##HYzLCoMwEADv@YothZKFCn3Q00Y/pRDixi7oKk2kQvDbbe0cZm4TpqnqQtiOoqGfWwYnY8pv9kNj5iTagfqB0@QDQ8otbaIZ9LzQ3mh3C5bPS3q2cqgvWPRZC0lt9STo3JVWiTaINs2C0S5I3CeGMM7ZuUpp/Q8HL2rRFAM/olUks243uMPjCw) but it gave me a negative result.

Comment: You have to have `#include <iostream>` and `using namespace std;` if you're going to use `cout` and `cin`. Once you fix that I can suggest some improvements.

Comment: `std::` is, in fact, not only much better, but also shorter here. `!=0` in the `while` condition can be removed.

Comment: [101 bytes](https://tio.run/##JYzNCgIhFEb3PoURxDUMYqKNf73JwGAZd@FVHANhmGe3pG9xDmfz@Zwvb@97P2LMqVSDaa3ltUTHkCon2fRwgEEUW0gFNGo820nQbFHiyeJM@gBrfSrlkZxr4vGP9KnGkCR7VQGa0HsfL3FBAsE2xn8LQEKzvU/8xu9f "C++ (gcc) – Try It Online")

Comment: You don't need the space between `#include` and `<iostream>`

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, 35 bytes

```java
x->x.stream().mapToInt(x->x).sum()
```

Takes a `List` of `Integer`s.

Comment: Nice Java solution :) But i think there are two problems : 1) It doesn't compile because there is a naming conflict between the outer `x` and the `x` inside the map. 2) Because OP explicitly disallowed usage of the character `-` *in the whole code*, sadly that should include the Java lambda arrow `->` which contains a `-` :(

Answer (score 1):

## x86-16 machine code, 8 bytes

```
33 D2       XOR  DX, DX         ; clear running sum (in DX)
        AN: 
AD          LODSW               ; load next value into AX
03 D0       ADD  DX, AX         ; add AX to running sum
E2 FB       LOOP AN             ; loop until CX = 0
C3          RET                 ; return to caller
```

Input size in `CX`, data in `[SI]`.  Output sum in `DX`.

Answer (score 1):

## SQL, 21 bytes

```
SELECT SUM(N) FROM T;
```

This assumes the numbers to be in table `T`, in a column named `N`.

Answer (score 1):

## [MAWP 1.1](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MAWP), 21 bytes

```
%@[~@~1A]_1A[%M_1A]%:
```

[Try it!](https://8dion8.github.io/MAWP/v1.1?code=%25%40%5B%7E%40%7E1A%5D_1A%5B%25M_1A%5D%25%3A&input=3%0A5%0A7%0A9)

Input taken as:

```
number_of_inputs
n1
n2
n3
...
nN
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), 57 bytes

```lua
print(load("return "..table.concat(arg,('').char(43)))())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFRCoAgDADQq4Q/bhCDUgiPs5ZUIBpjnn@91ya7f/p2gzb4gqDVpvYlEBmfrZKMLmzAeq8QI5I8rJATIgKiu@dUvOyHbzn9)

Answer (score 1):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 56 bytes

For once, in this challenge we can't use Java lambdas because its arrow `->` contains the `-` sign!

So i think the shortest way in Java to add N numbers
(unlike using a pre-built function that only adds 2 numbers, which has also been explicitly disallowed by OP)
without using `+` and `-`, is this approach:

```java
int f(int...a){return java.util.Arrays.stream(a).sum();}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZNNjptAEIX3PkWJFWiKFv1joGdkRTlAVrOMsujYZIQHPBbdWBmNvMwuR0guNxdxigbbSdsOEj96r/tV1Qeszc6k69XzYdt/beolLBtjLXwy9QbeZjMA64wj@VBvHHyL6coYM8lbV7m@28CadrPe1Q372HXm1TLrusq0sUmY7ds4edgfKGOKnqJ2L/UKqp1phjSovm@rpatWCGM2bE1n2oSKAx3Diq6yfeNgQeVH78Fbj6/WVS176R3bdrSu2cTxMWyxGDd9iN5//Yjuo/ffP6PkLoLobtR9xH52vbWWZo8fHWU@ff4Cpnuyx2580yCHRwSOAqZWRl2Nugh1rr2ukWeBobxRYBHouddLLP/VU@H1dI4yMLgoByNXSGfgyXGTxKD6NEYWhmVHPbtenWPKwxLal5d8jmkZxHGZ52QqqVGLYND8RDJsQp9Y4vwqzQz/wzO7TfRiKnViiqkIsXJxxooUcovsbbahc6Z70Yk8871ErKT4CzGmMnjNfJ7pM2bkKvxEhPbphcKiRMVRDfNmmBYCS023kmoKHDjQtORrasKvkVjQ01SO/pn94Q8)

Answer (score 1):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 19 bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY1LC8IwEITv/RVzbCUR@5A@oAePHjyJJ/EQa1sqaZQkFaT0t8dNPewys/OxYxohhXvdn21jcRKDwuwebYcuFNVR2U1Ui62ZRgcEgA9GYkKhe1PhoLX4Xs9WD6q/RRUuarCoMRMJfISEbs0k/akLeZ4x5AVDFtOkDDzZ0coThqL0giIek@N7hpRY7sEy9mKlaeXeZNH6/k2lVqrwX@FvS7C4Hw)

```scala
def f(a:Int*)=a.sum
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org), 29 (maybe 10?) bytes

Since Rust supports signed integers natively we have to use a signed type, but the challenge lets us choose the type beyond that, so I choose `i8` in order to save two bytes.

```rust
|n:&[i8]|n.iter().sum::<i8>()
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=TY89asQwEIVr6RSzzSKBtES215adn4sYE8wigSCrEEtOk92TpHGRnCB1DpID5B6ZiRs3M_Pe-xh47x_TnPLy5SOcxxCFhDf-5DJ4uP-cs9f2-xK7fR_scImHkN0k5CHN5667C_ZByJX5-WW3nPnnCcRpTE7BGJOEEKHnjIlXd9r1RkGhoBwU1FJtXXODCdqm3Pi6qRQ0VkGFRFUq0AViusEXtqUDI21Q6SM-RVYT2Bo6_mkcDYlqINVuX9eE0zA1hcYUkrMBazM2puSm_OhedsKLPVWRaxdsd-XXteyyrPsP)

Depending on how the rules should be interpreted it could be possible to solve it using only 10 bytes:

```rust
|n|n.sum()
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=TVA5bsMwEKypV6w7EiANU1J02VaRLm8wBENwSIBARMEilQOxX5JGRdLkR_5KqiytRs3u7OxggJmv72F0frpttYWuNZYy-IxelAddgbb0sX_fPX9YePJqaH0_7BB0e5PEdc1A1IAI9j-j16L4vdiLXbuxo2wmbn9kGxHdD0BPrVMcWusYGAuHiBD6qk6rg-QQc0gaDhnjS1Zu8IO0TBa8yFMOecEhRUWacBAxykSOFkUZAL6ExEs8oClqRRCWMoC7GkcejrQJV7m0zoI8DJmFp5Qxi0iDXRDSOqcGf1TnFdWhkKqy6u0eaW2s748Gu6GMsTkgRr5G17mBaZr3Pw)

by moving the type declarations into the driving code, but that requires the driving code to contain the `-` character, which I feel is against the rules.

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `S`, 0 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

That's right. No bytes. The `S` flag takes the sum.

### [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 1 [byte](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
S
```

1 byte flagless. Built-in for `sum`.

##### Screenshots

[image: Screenshot 1]
[image: Screenshot 2]

Answer (score 1):

## [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator), 50 bytes

```
\sum_{n=1}^{a.\operatorname{length}}a\left[n\right]
```

Takes input as array `a`

[View it on Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/z4z0bmpcfo)

Comment: As I mentioned in a comment on one of your other posts, variable input (the variable `a` in this case) is not allowed as per meta consensus. With that in mind, something like `f(a)=a.total` would be a much shorter alternative to what you have currently.

Answer (score 0):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 4 bytes

```
:sum
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0pN@R@UmhIdy1Vs9d@quDT3f0FRZl6JQnG0kYJxLBcSR8EEwdU1UtA1VDBQMFQwiv0PAA)

Takes the input as a block (list)

Answer (score 0):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 79 bytes

```
O`[^,\d]?\d\d*
\d\d*
$*
,[^,1]

^([^,1]1*),
$1;
,

\D?(1*);\1

^(\D)?(1*)
$1$.2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY49bgIxEIX7OcdGWlZvkMf2YlsUNEgpc4AYRKSlSJMCcf/lrRdQivl/883crvffv5/5o/@8zF@X7zPqdDrUqU6DrL4bBGzbSeTct8SGDaSzvUCkHg896321ZVyPm1Zy2m39PBu8eFqBOUlIkpFFRwTRXQRNNMCJY8MxqkGNLRuhOUgMBcUnIYUCcjBS9mS5lbZskQf1LyRs16grt/k3@z8eGuLrBCzypRSRMqIhLjwHTR65MGTueSx3eIHzQlDTBCRm8QE) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
O`[^,\d]?\d\d*
```

Sort the numbers.

```
\d\d*
$*
```

Convert the numbers to unary.

```
,[^,1]
```

Total the numbers that are less than zero.

```
^([^,1]1*),
$1;
```

Separate the numbers that are less than zero from those that are not less than zero.

```
,
```

Total the numbers that are not less than zero.

```
\D?(1*);\1
```

Add the less than zero total to the not less than zero total.

```
^(\D)?(1*)
$1$.2
```

Convert to decimal.

Adding nonnegative integers is much easier of course.

```
\d\d*
$*
1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P8/JiUmRYtLRYvL8P9/Qx0jHWMA) Explanation: Each integer is converted into unary and then the total is converted into decimal.

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 3 bytes

```
ＩΣＡ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5sbhEI7g0V8Mzr6C0REMTCKz//4@O1jU30VEwt9BRMDEEYmMdBV0jAyBhbqSjYGEJYgCldA2BPF1THQVjoFpdkEJLQxADrBpImIM4JrGx/3XLcgA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
  Ａ Input as an array
 Σ  Take the sum
Ｉ   Cast to string
    Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 18 bytes

```ruby
def f(*a)a.sum end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYpLDoAgDESv0qWY1sjHFI6DAXYao2Hh6bF1MZP5vLvv7xilNmjTnE1enn5APcu4ZCAOCBwRghV5BHKrGDuEmDTIRVYabQheWFIwWQ0/LcZaghkf)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pushy](https://github.com/FTcode/Pushy), 2 bytes

```
S#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Kygtzqj8/z9Y@f///0bGOiamOmZmOoaWOqYA)

As you can probably guess, `S` sums all values on the stack and `#` outputs this as a number.

Answer (score 0):

#### Javascript (40 characters)

`x=>eval(x.join(String.fromCharCode(43)))`

The boring and obvious way to do this, I guess.

#### Javascript (48 characters)

`x=>x.reduce((a,v)=>[...a,...Array(v)],[]).length`

A bit lame, but my first attempt. Concatenates arrays of the length of each number, then finds the total length of that array.

Answer (score 0):

## [Burlesque](https://github.com/FMNSSun/Burlesque), 6 bytes

```
ps{}ms
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYpRCoBACAWv8i4gpGvoXifYv4JK9is6u9nXDMxs895HXHNknvG8R2SSKcyhDG0gWUAm8F5wEAtoRVNQ9c6F/2mwMv0A)

Takes input as a space separated string from stdin. Explanation:

```
ps      # Parse input as block
    ms  # Map and sum result
  {}    # Empty mapping function
```

Answer (score 0):

## [C++ (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), <s>81</s> 75 bytes

```cpp
[](auto x){decltype(x)r;for(int a:x)r.insert(r.end(),a,0);return r.size();}
```

I used a generic lambda to avoid the need for `#include`.

It uses a temporary container, to which it appends lists of zeros of needed lengths. The output is the length of the resulting list.

Thanks to S.S. Anne for the idea of using `decltype`! I used `auto` earlier, and it was worse because I had to `clear` the list before working with it.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYzLCsIwEEXX5isG3CQQi69VE/sj4iKkowRqUibTUi399lofC3f33HO5vm03vnHxNruOE2Q4zeeL/ORBjTX6hh8tykGRuSaSITK4cqEixIzEkgqMtVTa6a0yhNxRBCpyeKJUZpqNWIfom65GsCFlJnT36q/r0XOiSrx/7y5EqcQoVpnrsvwqu5gK@nGnYa/hoOE4md/Ap47BWsiyV0ZMYn4B)

Comment: Try decltype...

Answer (score 0):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), 59 bytes

```
N S =S ' ' CHAR(43) ' ' INPUT :S(N)
O OUTPUT =EVAL(0 S)
END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87LT8rPMfn/308hWME2WEEdCJ09HIM0TIw1wRxPv4DQEAWrYA0/TS5/Bf/QEBDX1jXM0UfDQCFYk8vVz@X/f2MuEy5TAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Rockstar](https://codewithrockstar.com/), 66 bytes

```
listen to N
R's0
while N
cast N
let R be with N
listen to N

say R
```

[Try it here](https://codewithrockstar.com/online) (Code will need to be pasted in, with each input integer on an individual line)

Answer (score 0):

## [><> (Fish)](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 23 bytes

Takes input in unary, separated by NULL bytes.  A bit cheaty, let me know if you think this is valid or no.

```
i:0=?~:0(?v
       ;nl/
```

[Try it](https://mousetail.github.io/Fish/#eyJ0ZXh0IjoiaTowPT9+OjAoP3ZcbiAgICAgICA7bmwvIiwiaW5wdXQiOiIxIDEgMSAxIDAgMSAxIDEgMSAwIDEgMSAxIDEgMSAxIDAgMSAxIiwic3RhY2siOiIiLCJzdGFja19mb3JtYXQiOiJudW1iZXJzIiwiaW5wdXRfZm9ybWF0IjoibnVtYmVycyJ9)

## [><> (Fish)](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 34 bytes

Input must be length prefixed. Uses `p` to modify the source code at runtime to insert `+` and `-` instructions.

```
'V'2,61p0iv
:?!v$i $1 >59*91p
;n$/
```

[Try it](https://mousetail.github.io/Fish/#eyJ0ZXh0IjoiJ1YnMiw2MXAwaXZcbjo/IXYkaSAkMSA+NTkqOTFwXG47biQvIiwiaW5wdXQiOiI1IDEgMiAzIDQgNSIsInN0YWNrIjoiIiwic3RhY2tfZm9ybWF0IjoibnVtYmVycyIsImlucHV0X2Zvcm1hdCI6Im51bWJlcnMifQ==)

Comment: [16 bytes](https://mousetail.github.io/Fish/#eyJ0ZXh0IjoiXFx+bG47XG5cXGk6PyF+OjAoPyIsImlucHV0IjoiMSAxIDEgMCAxIDEiLCJzdGFjayI6IiIsInN0YWNrX2Zvcm1hdCI6Im51bWJlcnMiLCJpbnB1dF9mb3JtYXQiOiJudW1iZXJzIn0=) for the first answer, clearing out the whitespace and also fixing the result being off by one

Answer (score 0):

## [minigolf](https://github.com/jfioasd/minigolf/), 39 bytes

```
1i,ny*_:1<sv,1s/_:,:ny=!ns,,___s,_s,T*_
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=7RrbctvGdaaP_Io1Na5ACaJI-hKXsTJx7KZOq1SupKZuGQ6zApfk2iAA40KT7vRL-pI-NP_UfE3POYvLAlhAlJuZ5iEYzWi5u-ey57bnHOCfPwS7eOV73__4q3_JdeCHMYt2UScdrnm8ysY8XAY8jESnQ_9CdpZP9Z-Fy2QtvPgVrVhzETmhDGLpe2fdtfTk0ncX3V7ngCnQPp_PZzyFsQ4X0hWHNqw2PfEuEEAuisNeRr2C4mQDCEyg3EEuALgbxX4oZnGYiK5560q4AW58FUoPjp6yzTYijBCFtfBD5qyE81Z6S_bs-oIlwZzHIup1G7lyfjquLpI4SGLmyihm_oI5_lwEPjAaMQ5_KBtgq5mT-CfkxHN3LCAhXV9cMR6zeCWY8ObIl9gKJ0GUyArQjwAi5Yj-IU-RBWtygeYT9TdjIkb4rO5m0H8EkDgjtjK2BrATj4p0u91_J_Hi5Ml_DofS9nZHs_HwabSxh9HpbGyPvd3ZPS-y7dlsFtnwd300U9t_PBoCaCeKufMW0EymQNsDUUb5DxxZYPX9KJ5Lrx8KPrd6x91v4Qz9KHCBDRp30AAkkx78RZPxyXCqWIeTuMKzZI99xgbjXHROEqKPiA13YS2fht1ozhYu99gZWfW4JG_FXZ8HAcjUQoVbax5Yfji3CWmvV2ATbiTaoGm_dmDCpn7l0zM538LSoNOZi4VSloUy7ynEoYgSN1bCUgRmwDIB4M-IVENDks98ayshCQ9sLwQH0ZGlElA4KozDNMrjcHI4zogcn7FhaZNw823Tw3HNTFOwkypYiSxCD-qwxVlLoo80aeuPdu5iCviVpSnH92LpJaJ0-PyUB-wLsQRR5c6cunFFoWZREAOTrmYKGe7up11GporjWRfpwHFmoJ4Sglisg0Kt2fN-BdE4FcQEbJzdAyR2ty6vDDyVWeAHVm_Kjmm-tNmFXfqm0qIPsSOcZbhcI4L8XDMDGxoCENGkO-hOmwjQ-qeV9bLKi929_Vkoo-ged-sW07KFXBhURKRbWIMYUngZOphaHtdMq6atCvFPU-KwH7aaMIUiTkIvDQVqMSWerqg5FTAWLo9jiH-8IV7k_PISqxQEJUVA9DMTx6iwDLtsi3k1QTWwuplFyTpnNA53tSOr9fT-cURQF0oejwmZzSE8EO7Yn91wEJcfyqXNcJiSmculzC4b_K0cDLeV74tiH63dJxzoD2oh30erp6dntK6fNN1H3CSefJfIxc7aplz4BoVsK7bj-TFO-2Xh-ma5-ooQRCdnlXhvo5lnQeR31a86UXVqvCe3lXsyx7-dDMYp_LTQNl5N20k6P54aWMgyNcxd4pV-6MzMtgYzS29t5AYi6zjDOSybWTat7rqy5QGG7Z7AxCelErObnfXaZpEIUh5R4_BrMpgWIptMK5p6XffyqEFLk2mbp_gY0lsVuplB5midv7yy2eXLq4ogYbqHF0JZlCkCWARrBSCDrPzyRZMfDGAazqH4kIqLXpVWymwcci8KfHC78zz6lL0UB_YHGVhH55g3dSjPFHNg50vuYjHDQxlLgVr4OyHojuHCHKoMuHtEYwjOMSSFMRuhpjjmNO5ObTi-bYPQsCXa-HMYj9JxVIwPu5AWPEjnN9qe99r4LCP6kntz8KqCJkuTCbXvqQZzoNH2tfEHbXyj7d9p8_e1-VNtfA_3dP4BMnQckN9oACx9I8Id86QjSMeRvxYMfROSmr5SWZjAVQHWQyqyGZYeI5u8_MEo1eHS9W-4C6WJo_-kBF6fKLLXysXIK36uXTWYSYHQ0n1K9f23YgclCc1jSCBCPfY0W5_IadlGD9hlMpdYWHE47Fdr8GtHxoqfykYr5m_BuNL8O_HmUDdjtaRolDYj-2_oNubeUlgFcXaisdUrs6KoPPeDHemdkHwnv4NaLRS1jVmhotL_ljQ4r5Uw_zvWJK8_9eBSA1eUJoWips3oiMGiHqmlu9oh9LLlTD-SmZ0KZqp0NGzVRATk-TUPMIFWyXi_hHSF1Q1k-RCvYTQZjsvZJOBbZTlYisj1_aBJFamp7aGJn60oq8sxZfLEmCHdx6eaIFZYIn0AluKiAUFCKGeCOysjV4qkchuIi9hIgKnjYa_Xqe1HB9nOuIuhB_-VK1Uk21AZQtiSKYytMJjrwnIuqsnBwIxaTbdmeba-gWo6ZVATMigwyXYs5XaB7OlktQpxS9heJdGKbTuNyLZm4DEBz5OgGZJ-YPgwY4jUYd5zAwqEsrPhaJoZE47tYocR7YbQ-ptKHWXibNTA2T1Cce4vpQNXDGbE1xdX_WZ0Q4jO9QRUV7uZzq-JznPuutREOy2G72W8wtZYvxpYyDEKweoB64UMhRMzB3G8PwW2VW-tZiqcmhb9N770yEicVWiXea1CoN2rOpD3qrap6lZinJjGu7wmLXyUp7VHhf-NtdQzzbJ-pYydOpYW1vZ-iBe3H6DTS98ro1adyJLj1pYpgbwOE2Gkd0T01okLak3r1zvokly4B2ZlAsWnZH9ZfdxgcbqiXuz4XDpgJFFjalDcR0NzGNw7hagxejI0x8vmNKKGon4HmlESo3vcf-mBPuIOrFAw3YMVJY8MSqarCjW9AeeFsv5DXS_4cJvdlJ3HbvUkfELz9YpPnibfNJ8vzEXOjhhvaICWLi_D7ZbZHYizOCoHhDe349POBwDmW1TzuGPyOCgYweOiZH13bwMgAIWLI6a4X8WBD78lgOELDcQ8mbakctn5BnV4Og5xyiG5LGU_oxcgOWTRklmxkVe-eyhHNbVMFFsz-KISRwRFqc2rwdiM55eQ8vMNKZc2O79rSKnYBHWJbHZpymv3NCzdyY9vd_L7qqTy54nrM2vuQ12N-Vl-0jLbdzliiatzdh9OZeTgtKuSrY1Ub4Rv4-GAXYSFp1LkRSVVErPLlsCSqfyyoVFe475w08uP89IG5_vFS00UTF56fss9UTG201OyNpO5eWRu-ApXQOYK1oMVMJOQwcJdNWq2YM9svbyo-bBht-FuIpqRwBYzmkSh8QOqVmIfkZUNWrUDdRmY8EjCE4p3iYhi5oktJOfOzoHrrWdspYHzBMj7yTDXHZMRg3Q-3tVqpdtttdVGzbZ5Z5u8zRbvboNNfSxNrn4qV_xuRaTFJdCvkG-z0rzbv2_QoaZDShFser_8oOIHwKDZTnZ0nhE7Oqq0KtqOUEJOsOdm7Aeq3hfeEgpYf4Hy-jgiqLrzhpvrTL2Df5dwV8Y7k622Zkl369u2xd09L-Z94-3_pclY4bRUqqsW_229l6epzqOIxSvu9dkV5Pw8ZL7nlpXz0TkEsnXOnpazo5QDqLy6g-HowcNHjz958htiheJaKKIA0gi5EepNbjt2WfoIKEf87IvnL3775e9eEtrhABLB4SctzasBuF0B019IeitYw4xC-4pQPmi5dh6MjIC_V_7bosTRwHiWP5x__ceLV3-6vLomDCd0nJNhM54TdR4NrvVEfya0g_6jZoywaAT9Rp3p0eOWQz16bAT9S6qaFnnAohH0dQo6etgGO3poBP6rAh49aYEdPTGC_i1juZ1n_Fav6MnRR1_ad34OtWbVR4zqxUrEFqG_NnzRSFS0DkbesSCK-39Fkq9TPa2VSp-dQUldD7NAETuPaUsNu-e1PVtzXyV_dycbs2fi5E3LjZqTqLXysRX6xtQBxac9jc6RAQ6gbmii5p8Ffetp3VeXr2_mnPnjrCXrQ-jb7nexFygr7Vz1OqIZONSZzZw2ewMWkilhsZV2YPMvE8i8NIFqDVz1BqJOLf3atHRkMEo7fcfaU1-Ofv_DZGiz0VT9-i8)

Answer (score 0):

## Regex, 1 byte

```
x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/V@Ump5aYZuXWq4QlJruWlGgkfC/4n@CXklRZq6Gpo6Cerq6JhdXmoKtQrGCrZ1CsV5uYklyhgZYl6ZeTmpeekkGF1dyfl5xfk6qXk5@ukaahlJFhUJFhZKmJlZxMMYtCyNxq1FAKIIrxeCgA6BZ/wE) Takes input as space-delimited unary, outputs using the number of matches. [This](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/250716/100664) [is](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/249432/100664) [a](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/250193/100664) [standard](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/250184/100664) [I/O](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/250320/100664) [format](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/250137/100664) for regex that just happens to trivialise this challenge.

Answer (score 0):

## Swift, 87 bytes

The xor & carry based approach.
The return type of a function in Swift is defined using the arrow like `f() -> Int` with a "minus" character, so my function needs to print the value and not return it :-) (that way actually 5 bytes shorter than returning the result)

```
func s(_ a:[Int]){var r=0;for var c in a{while 0 != c{(r,c)=(r^c,(r&c)<<1)}};print(r)}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Gema](http://gema.sourceforge.net/), 35 characters

```
<N>=@set{s;@add{${s;};$0}}
?=
\Z=$s
```

Takes an input string with anything separated numbers.

Sample run:

```
bash-5.2$ gema '<N>=@set{s;@add{${s;};$0}};?=;\Z=$s' <<< '-64, -64, 16'
-112
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0/NTfz/38bPztahOLWkutjaITElpVoFyKi1VjGoreWyt@WKibJVKf7/X9fMREcBTBiaAQA) / [Try all test cases online!](https://tio.run/##lVJNT@MwED3Xv2I2yhKQYjW203yoBLoHDnsBiSOlWmUTs6CFpoqDtFK3v707M6algDjsZfyePX7znuWftbvftrZ5rHsL8hsM1g0/mtrZ6liM5pGKQUeLyhDWHqeEyxhUgkSVxPIYciJ8VMRQEMmIyEkMBpnUzLI0Biy0oXTBWyYGEpI8IvHdO0wHCXehD6ledYxCXVmwsilZKDXoqdTsw2TZzrwXzHb@Y5ggLV/0P6RI3gfxHg6y4Fh6BJke5kGZjDMpvc/0Ppbn@2Qfwu0CmjcBsRh@rtTow5Q4MaVgapKwd5mjiRztpiiUskscIXMMXJQECtJHxiHINTWWNNV3Y8mJ8DBdihMhVv3DcriD6C98lfnEAa0qebNqrLfLCKLvy9XzgOu1dc@PBC7@rGwz2Bbh1e9IiLuuhwdqwgpBuP6y/2jz2WITTKHtxKjn21UQHoNt7juQ1Mq3Apw27lbD@Jd9qseubxhAtD29PKtmzg5rN53VbbsOEWymYbLZiPNK3N5UodtGcBIIMfqPPPupQeg9EVq/WvbH6BvI63x@0FdVn7UuFnB05IPRm5Cptlva7T8)

Answer (score 0):

## [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), 3 characters

```
add
```

Takes the input as array.

Sample run:

```
bash-5.2$ jq 'add' <<< '[-64, -64, 16]'
-112
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyr8/z8xJeX//2hdMxMdBTBhaBYLAA) / [Try all test cases online!](https://tio.run/##lZJPT8JAEMXP7KcYG6SQdJPubumfmCZ68ODJxGttDLZLQEmLtCQm6GfHmd1aIODBy@y@7ey899v0ddYs9qUuVrONBn4HrW7al2LW6HTMBpmbCQ9k7uapMkp2KjAq8UD4JEVidORBZKT9HHsQGxkayaceKNJcWh0GHmAxR0LG9lB5YEZya@h3d3plPvq2F7NxcTxRCfTgsXVRiR0ZKMyZSJtMhWGP1Y0OezIPpnSQ/Hpd4PPPEbtMx5QYwjwTD05IcVxoaYU80J4DdycH5gvYPbo6Rcei7JMGSp7wo3tggMXUtzw8wkgRAgQ4LjCp0YpH@BBxQpuYXFAZKGKgxoS8bTeWiIQ1lAmbMLbeLKt2Du4XXPMobIBW4Z@sEutz5YL7UK23La5PutmuaHP/udZFq0vcPr67jM3rDSypCSs4w91V/3tmt/m3cwNlzQYbczt1hmPQxaIGTq3mloNubx/g7mdluXdh4jA2@Ee@fooztB602x0i2M@YA8g7y4760vSv1jyH0cgGJUYKVdaV3v8A)

Answer (score -1):

### Java, 15 bytes

```
Math.addExact()
```

You give it your two variables as parameters

Comment: Welcome to CGCC! We don't allow predefined variables as input, however you can submit just the function itself as `Math.addExact` as a solution instead, since it fulfills the challenge specifications.